# Parse.com Javascript sdk key

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I'm using the Javascript SDK to send push notification from my node.js server.
The SDK uses js key + API key.

When I turn off the client can push notification, the server is unable to send with "Client-initiated push isn't enabled"

How am I supposed to securely send push notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node.js server is considered a "client" to Parse.com, that is why you get that error message. I would suggest keeping client push turned off, if possible. Then create a Cloud Code function on Parse.com that will send the push notification. You can call this new function from your node.js server.

Since both node.js and the Cloud code are in JavaScript, you should be able to move the push code fairly painlessly.

As for writing a Cloud Code function that can be called from your node.js server:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

Then from your node.js code, you can call that function by:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
  success: function(result) {
    // result is 'Hello world!'
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});
```